# NODE JS Update specific filed in collection without affecting other fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to make a generic function for update the data in the collection, right now I am able to update a specific field.

```
var myquery = { address: "Valley 345" };
var newvalues = { $set: {name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" } };
dbo.collection("customers").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
if (err) throw err;
 console.log("1 document updated");
 db.close();
});
```

But I want my function to update any field I pass through. Is there any way to pass dynamic fields and same will get while update. Like

```
var newvalues = { $set: {name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" } };
```

this part will be dynamic without fixing filed names.

Please help to achieve this.

Comment: Where will these dynamic values come from?

Comment: from, app, right now is coming from postman...like {"email":"abc@gmail.com"} then same method can update {"views":"100"}

Comment: If so you can do something like `newvalues = { $set: req.body}`

Comment: in this case, it will add new value in req.body with other data in collection.

Comment: use [lodash npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash), after import use it `{ $set: _.pick(req.body, ["name", "address"]) }`

Comment: If you're using mongoose, you can create schema for that collection and the field that's not in the schema will not affect the update